# HoganTemplates not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hogan.js

I am trying out some javascript templates I have a Rails application. I am using the HoganTemplates and mustache I have a js file with the following snippet

```
var data = {name: 'Name', age: 'Age'}

var test = ($('<div class="test"></div>').append(HoganTemplates['sample']).render(data);
```

I have my template 'sample' located in app/assets/javascripts/templates/sample.mustache

sample.mustache

```
<h1> {{name}} </h1>
<h2> {{age}} </age>
```

When I run my application, the console shows that

> **'Uncaught ReferenceError: HoganTemplates is not defined'**

I followed the [hogan_assests](https://github.com/leshill/hogan_assets)

Thanks

Comment: Is that just a typo? e.g. `HoganTeamplates['sample']` should be `HoganTemplates['sample']`